# jQuery mobile table in columntoggle mode / column button does not work after ajax call

Tags: jquery-mobile, html-table

Here is the problem:

A js script is calling a PHP script via ajax. This script builds some html code, resulting a h3 title and a table block in `columntoggle` mode. The result is inserted inside the my_content div and a call to `table()` draws the table in a jqm way.

```
function get_table()
{   $.ajax({
    type:'post',dataType:'text',cache:false
    ,url:'script.php'
,data:({token:tok, sort:srt})
,success:function(data,status,request)
    {   $('#my_content').html(data);
        if($('#my_table').length) $('#my_table').table();
}
}

<body>
<div id="my_content"></div>
</body>
```

here is an idea of what the PHP script builds:

```
<div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">

<div class="ui-corner-all custom-corners">
<h3>My Table</h3>
</div>

<div class="ui-body ui-body-a">

<table id="my_table" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" class="ui-responsive table-stroke" data-column-btn-theme="a" data-column-btn-text="Columns" data-column-popup-theme="a">

<thead>
<tr>
<th data-priority="" colspan="1"><a href="#" onclick="re_sort('def');">Default</a></th>
<th data-priority="1" colspan="2"><a href="#" onclick="re_sort('fil');">Files</a></th>
...
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<td>$type</td>
<td>$number</td>
<td>$ratio</td>
...
</tbody>

<tfooter>
<td>total</td>
<td>$sum_number</td>
<td>100%</td>
...
</tfooter>

</table>

</div>

</div>
```

That works fine, even the column button at the top of the table that let the user choose what column he wants to display or not.

Now in the table header, there are links. They call a js re_sort function to change the sort criteria and then redisplay the table.

```
function re_sort(new_srt)
{   srt=new_srt;
    get_table();
}
```

That works fine too.

My problem is after the table has been redrawed with the new sort criteria, the column button has no more effect on showing/hiding the table columns.

I've tried to clean the table object and his events with :

```
$('#my_table').empty(); or $('#my_content').empty();
```

before

```
$('#my_content').html(data);
```

and a few other tricks, but i'm stuck!.

note:

```
$('#my_table').trigger('create');
```

does not work too.

It seems that I must call something more to tell jqm I want the table to be re-processed as a new one.

UPDATE: I wrote a example to demonstrate the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/komet163s/2P8BG/20/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this **$("#my_table-popup-popup").remove();** here:

```
$('#my_content').html(code);
$("#my_table-popup-popup").remove();  
if($('#my_table').length) $('#my_table').table();
```

I found the solution in this answer:
[JQuery Mobile update table via AJAX and column-toggle stops working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761771/jquery-mobile-update-table-via-ajax-and-column-toggle-stops-working)

Seems work: http://jsfiddle.net/2P8BG/26/