# JQuery Mobile update table via AJAX and column-toggle stops working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I'm creating a small app using JQM 1.4.2 and I'm having an issue where I am updating a table without a page refresh using ajax. This works well and my table (the whole table) is updated BUT after an update the `data-mode='columntoggle'` no longer works - the button is there but any selections you make to display columns no longer works at all.

Can anyone think of a reason why this would happen? Code below:

Main page

```
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a" >   
         <div id='visualUnitTable'>
        <!-- list loads dynamically - popup & jquery at bottom of page -->  

         </div>

    <!------------------POPUP------------------- --> 
       <div data-role='popup' id='popupVisualUnit' data-theme='a' data-overlay-theme='a' data-dismissible='false'  style='min-width: 300px;'>
                <div data-role='header' data-theme='a'>
                    <h1>Visual Check</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role='main' class='ui-content'>
                    <form id='frmVisualUnit'>
                        <!--using ajax to create the form-->

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->
```

table page (ive removed a load of php from here for ease of reading!!):

```
<table data-role='table' id='visualUnitListTable' data-mode='columntoggle' class='ui-body-b ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive' data-column-btn-mini='true' data-column-btn-text='Columns to Display' data-column-btn-theme='c' data-column-popup-theme='a' >
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th data-priority='1'>Unit No.</th>
                        <th data-priority='1'>Size Code</th>
                        <th data-priority='2'>Size</th>
                        <th data-priority='3'>Week Rate</th>
                        <th data-priority='3'>Month Rate</th>
                        <th data-priority='2'>Overlocked</th>
                        <th data-priority='2'>Visual Check</th>
                        <th data-priority='1'>Status</th>
                        <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
echo"<tr>
        <td><a href='./unit_Details.php?unitid=" . $row['unitid'] . "'>" . $row['unitno'] . "</a></td>
        <td>" . $row['sizecode'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['usize'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['wrate'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['mrate'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['overlocked'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['visual'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>
        <td><div id='custom-border-radius'><a onclick= DisplayVisualCheckPopUP('" . $row ['unitid'] ."') class='ui-btn ui-icon-edit ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all' data-rel='popup' data-position-to='window' data-transition='pop'>" . $row['unitno'] . "</a></div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Click on the edit button to open a popup which when you close re-writes the table with the updated info.
ajax to re-load the table without refreshing the whole page:

```
      function LoadVisualUnitTable() {
                    $.post('unit_DisplayVisualTable.php', 'unitSearchBox=<?php echo $_POST ['unitSearchBox'];?>&choiceUnitSearch=<?php echo $_POST ['choiceUnitSearch'];?>&choiceDeletedUnit=<?php echo $_POST ['choiceDeletedUnit'];?>&selectSiteUnit=<?php echo $_POST ['selectSiteUnit'];?>&choiceUnitSearchCri=<?php echo $_POST ['choiceUnitSearchCri'];?>&selectUnitStatus=<?php echo $_POST ['selectUnitStatus'];?>&sid=RI201310111345581600', function(data) {
                        $("#visualUnitTable").html(data); //<!-- load data to div -->
                        $("#visualUnitTable").trigger('create'); //<!-- load data to css -->
                    });
                    return false;
                };
```

I was thinking that perhaps I need to just reload row by row - any thoughts on that? Otherwise any ideas would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Calling $("#visualUnitTable").html(table).enhanceWithin(); seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/CaBjR/2/, maybe you can reproduce the problem in my jsFiddle?

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer! It does do the same thing in your jsfiddle, if you load the table once, the "columns to display" button works fine, if you press the button again, the table reloads, with all the columns showing but the button is no longer active. This is whats happening with my code, on the first page load it works fine, after I do an update to the table so reload the table the "columns to display" button no longer works. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: also I tried this code out and it doesn't work for me :( $("#visualUnitTable").html(table).enhanceWithin(); displays nothing whereas $("#visualUnitTable").html(data).enhanceWithin(); does the same as I already have!

Comment: I have updated the fiddle and put it in an answer. Ialso changed my variable name to 'data' instead of 'table' to remove that confusion ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like jQM is keeping the popup with the list of columns from the first load of the table, so after subsequent loads it is not recreating the list.  There is probably a more 'official' way to do this, but a quick workaround is to just remove the dynamic popup from the DOM each time you refresh the table:

```
$("#visualUnitListTable-popup-popup").remove();        
$("#visualUnitTable").html(data).enhanceWithin();
```

Given your table id of `visualUnitListTable`, jQM creates a popup with an id of `visualUnitListTable-popup-popup`, so you can call remove() on that element right before updating the the table HTML.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/CaBjR/4/)**

Comment: that worked - thank you very much, it's appreciated!! :D