# Update single column values of Table

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

We are using below code to display results in table & now for **commission1** column values we need to **update** values in database with help of **ajax**.

[image]

Under commission1 column, we need to add "Edit" button, once we click on "Edit" button, it should allow to edit that value 10 . once we click on " update" button, it should save values in Database.

[image]

[image]

**display.php**

```
function getDesignerCollection() {
    $user_home = new USER();

    if (!$user_home->is_logged_in()) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        die();
    }

    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();

    $i=0;
    while($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $responce[$i]=array($data['userID'],
                      . $data['phone'],
                      $data['commission1'],
                      .
                      .                  
        $i++;
    }
    echo json_encode($responce);
}
```

**connection**

```
try {
    $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

**script**

```
<script>
    var colsOption = [  
        {id: 'phone' , header: "phone" , width :"130"},
    //Edit commission

    <?php 
    $count="SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users";
    $i=1;

    foreach ($dbo->query($count) as $row) {
        $m=$i%2;
        $sid='s' . $row['commission1'];
        echo "
        <tr class='r$m'>
            <td>
                <input type=button id=$sid value='Edit' onclick=edit_field($row[commission1])> 
            </td>
        </tr>";
        $i=$i+1;
    }
    ?>
//Edit commission end
    ];
</script>
```

for displaying commission we were using this code : `{id: 'commission1' , header: "commission1" , width :"120"},]` as we need to edit values of commission1 column, now we are using above code under `//Edit commission` but now table is not displaying.

I am new to coding & checked lot of other posts before asking here....

Comment: no need to create td in script just give id to the commission1 column and change the value using `<td id='comm'>commission1 </td>` `$("#comm").text($row[commission1]);`

Comment: @NishantNair i tried what you suggested, but still its giving same result for me....  i tried as `echo "<tr class='r$m'>
<td id='comm'>commission1 </td> 
</tr>";` & `<script>$("#comm").text($row[commission1]);</script>`

Comment: you just to use '<script>$("#comm").text($row[commission1]);</script>' in js script

Comment: @NishantNair when i used these codes  in script, than table will display : `{id: 'commission1' , header: "commission1" , width :"120"}, $("#commission1").text($row[commission1]);` , but i need to to update values of commission1 column

Comment: @NishantNair am i going in right way? include php code inside script to fetch details of commission from DB & trying to update those values......

Comment: requesting to please visit [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761771/jquery-mobile-update-table-via-ajax-and-column-toggle-stops-working ]

Comment: @NishantNair Thanks a lot for your guidance......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this steps.

Add this is to user col creation  script

```
{id: 'commission1' , header: "commission1" , width :"120",renderer : my_CommisionRenderId},
```

**my_CommisionRenderId function**

```
function my_CommisionRenderId(value ,record,columnObj,grid,colNo,rowNo)
{
    var no= record[columnObj.fieldIndex]; 
    return record[8]+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type=button id=sid value='Edit' onclick=edit_fieldDisplay('"+record[0]+"','"+record[1]+"','"+record[8]+"','"+record[2]+"','"+record[3]+"')>";  
}
```

**edit_fieldDisplay function**

```
function edit_fieldDisplay(TxtUserID,TxtDesignName,TxtCommission,TxtEmail,TxtPhone){ 
    $('#DivCommissionEdit').show();

    $('#TdTxtUserID').html(TxtUserID+'<input  type="hidden" id="TxtBxTxtUserID" value=""/>');
    $('#TxtBxTxtUserID').val(TxtUserID);

    $('#TdTxtDesignName').html(TxtDesignName+'<input  type="hidden" id="TxtBxTdTxtDesignName" value=""/>');
    $('#TxtBxTdTxtDesignName').val(TxtDesignName);

    $('#TdTxtPhone').html(TxtPhone+'<input  type="hidden" id="TxtBxTdTxtPhone" value=""/>');
    $('#TxtBxTdTxtPhone').val(TxtPhone);

    $('#TdTxtEmail').html(TxtEmail+'<input  type="hidden" id="TxtBxTdTxtEmail" value=""/>'); 
    $('#TxtBxTdTxtEmail').val(TxtEmail);

    $('#TdTxtCommission').html('<input  type="text" id="TxtBxTdTxtCommission" value="'+TxtCommission+'"/>');

}
```

**Update_field function**

```
function Update_field( ){
        var NewTxtCommission=$('#TxtBxTdTxtCommission').val();
        var NewTxtEmail=$('#TxtBxTdTxtEmail').val();
        var NewTxtPhone=$('#TxtBxTdTxtPhone').val();
        var NewTxtDesignName=$('#TxtBxTdTxtDesignName').val();
        var NewTxtUserID=$('#TxtBxTxtUserID').val();
        if(confirm("Do you want to proceed ?")){
            $.post("ajaxChangeCommision.php","NewTxtCommission="+NewTxtCommission+"&NewTxtEmail="+NewTxtEmail+"&NewTxtPhone="+NewTxtPhone+"&NewTxtDesignName="+NewTxtDesignName+"&NewTxtUserID="+NewTxtUserID,function(result,status,xhr){
                alert(result);
                $('#DivCommissionEdit').hide();
                $('#DivCommissionResponse').show();
                $('#DivCommissionResponse').html(result);
                window.location.reload()
            })
            .fail(function(){  alert("something went wrong please try again."); });
        }

    }
```

**Add this in your head section**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#DivCommissionEdit').hide();
});
</script>
```

**Add this in your html section**

```
<div style="margin: 10px; display: block;background:#e6ae64;" align="center" id="DivCommissionEdit">
    <div style="color: #000">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;">CHANGE THE COMMISSION HERE</span>
    </div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr >
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Designer Name</td>
            <td>Phone No</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Commission</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="TdTxtUserID"> </td>
            <td id="TdTxtDesignName"> </td>
            <td id="TdTxtPhone"> </td>
            <td id="TdTxtEmail"> </td>
            <td id="TdTxtCommission"> </td>
            <td id=""><input type=button id="" value="UPDATE" onclick="Update_field();"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="margin: 10px; display: none;background:#4bb458;" align="center" id="DivCommissionResponse"></div>
```

**ajaxChangeCommision.php**

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "xxx";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxxxx";

    $NewConn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);

if( isset($_POST['NewTxtCommission']) && !empty($_POST['NewTxtCommission']) && $_POST['NewTxtCommission']!="" )
{  $NewTxtCommission=$_POST['NewTxtCommission'];  }else{$NewTxtCommission=0;}

if( isset($_POST['NewTxtEmail']) && !empty($_POST['NewTxtEmail']) && $_POST['NewTxtEmail']!="" )
{  $NewTxtEmail=$_POST['NewTxtEmail'];  }else{$NewTxtEmail="";}

if( isset($_POST['NewTxtPhone']) && !empty($_POST['NewTxtPhone']) && $_POST['NewTxtPhone']!="" )
{  $NewTxtPhone=$_POST['NewTxtPhone'];  }else{$NewTxtPhone=0;}

if( isset($_POST['NewTxtDesignName']) && !empty($_POST['NewTxtDesignName']) && $_POST['NewTxtDesignName']!="" )
{  $NewTxtDesignName=$_POST['NewTxtDesignName'];  }else{$NewTxtDesignName="";}

if( isset($_POST['NewTxtUserID']) && !empty($_POST['NewTxtUserID']) && $_POST['NewTxtUserID']!="" )
{  $NewTxtUserID=$_POST['NewTxtUserID'];  }else{$NewTxtUserID=0;}


$CommissionUpdateQry="UPDATE tbl_users SET commission1='".$NewTxtCommission."' WHERE userID='".$NewTxtUserID."' ;";
    $queryResult=TRUE;
    if( isset($NewConn) && !empty($NewConn) && $NewConn!="" ) {
        $queryResult=mysqli_query($NewConn,$CommissionUpdateQry);
    }

    if($queryResult==TRUE){
        echo "Commission Updated Successsfully";
    }else{
        echo "something went wrong please try again";
    }

?>
```

Comment: kk Take your time.

Answer (score 0):

You should build your html code inside the body and not in the script section. So move the below code to body section.
`

```
<?php 
    $count="SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users";
    $i=1;

    foreach ($dbo->query($count) as $row) {
        $m=$i%2;
        $sid='s' . $row['commission1'];
        echo "
        <tr class='r$m'>
            <td>
                <input type=button id=$sid value='Edit' onclick=edit_field($row[commission1])> 
            </td>
        </tr>";
        $i=$i+1;
    }
    ?>`
```

Comment: Thanks, as you said i tried your code outside table, now `Edit` button is displaying outside the table. I need to display `edit` button inside table, can you please help me for that......

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 The current tr element is being appended directly to the body rather than to table. Since you are using grid widget, it will be easier for you use the available options in the grid to manipulate columns. Check this link for an example https://github.com/sigmawidgets/Sigma-grid-AJAX-grid-for-php-java---.net/blob/master/demos/example_column_editor.html

Comment: @user5348fh8y5 if you are not able to get it working, please create a plunkr/jsfiddle and share.

Comment: sure, thanks for suggestion, i will try that link that you gave and update you.......